# get specific id which is displayed from foreach loop to the script code

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, foreach

In my leave approval system admin can see the employee leave using foreach loop. Admin should approve or disapprove leave using the leave id.Im not clear on how to take the leave id from the view to my javascript file.

```
    <script> 

    $(function(){

    var BASE_URL = "http://localhost/employeemgt/index.php/";

        $('#pedingLeaveRequest').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var current_leave_id = button.data('id');
            var modal = $(this);

            modal.find('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val(current_leave_id); 

            alert(current_leave_id); 
        });     


       $('#approvebtn').click(function(){               
         var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
         alert(id);
            $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/approveLeave', 

                {'id': id}, 
                function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                if(result.error){
                    // error                        
                    alert('try again');
                }else{
                    // suceess
                    alert('Leave has been approved!');
                }
            });              
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is the js file. The variable id is not working.

```
<?php
                        foreach ($leave as $row) {
                            echo '
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li class="media border-bottom border-top py-3">
                                    <img class="mr-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">'.$row->user_name.'</h5>
                                      <p class="mb-0 mt-0">'.$row->leave_start.' to '.$row->leave_end.'</p>
                                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->leave_type.'</p>
                                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->id.'</p>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pedingLeaveRequest">View Request</button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>               
                            </ul>
                            ';
                        }
                    ?>
```

above is the code where it display leave to the admin.

the following is the modal

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="pedingLeaveRequest" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Leave Request</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                    <p class="mt-0 mb-1 font-weight-bold">Name</p>
                    <p class="mt-0 mb-0"><?php echo ''.$row->user_name.' '; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_leave_id" value=""/>
            <button type="button" id="declinebtn" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
            <button type="button" id="approvebtn" class="btn btn-primary">Approve</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so what's the final outcome you are trying to achieve?

Comment: _“The variable id is not working.”_ - well of course it isn’t, the element with the id `approvebtn` doesn’t have any `data` attribute.

Comment: I want to update the database for the leave status as approved or disapproved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modal window, you have to add an input to store the current leave id. In your modal html add the following line.

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_leave_id" value=""/>
```

If you still don't have modal show event handler, add the following block. It saves the current leave id so when approve button is clicked, it will know which record to update.

```
$('#pedingLeaveRequest').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var current_leave_id = button.data('id');
    var modal = $(this);

    modal.find('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val(current_leave_id); 
});
```

In your first code block - #approvebtn click handler..

**Change:**

```
var id = $(this).attr('data');
```

**To:**

```
var id = $('input[name="current_leave_id"]').val();
```

Comment: Still didn't work. But in the console the value changed from "null" to value : ""

Comment: Can you update your codes above? Or pastebin them if your prefer that.

Comment: * In your modal html, insert my first code snippet above your buttons.

Comment: I have updated my above code according to the changes.

Comment: No it do not show any errors. The alert shows 'try again'

Comment: In approvebtn click handler, when you do alert(id); what's the output?

Comment: This works fine when we use a definite leave id value as : var id = '17';

Comment: Can you try alert(current_leave_id); ? Inside your modal show handler.

Comment: The alert says "undefined"

Comment: * make sure your button's data-id attribute has value.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to update it  bacuase i changed it and updated as above.

Comment: In your View Request button add attribute - `data-id="'.$row->id.'"`

Comment: OMG it works fine now thanks to you. Thanks a lot. I've been stuck with this for days. You are a god.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the function on "onclick". In that function, you can add id which you get from foreach loop. but you have to create function leaveArrove(id) in javascript. add your javascript code in that function.

Try this

Ex:
Javascript code:

```
function leaveArrove(id){

  $.post(BASE_URL +  'admin/AdminDashboardController/approveLeave', 

    {'id': id}, 
    function(result){
        console.log(result);
    if(result.error){
        // error
        alert('try again');
    }else{
        // suceess
        alert('Leave has been approved!');
    }
 });              
}
```

Html Code:

```
<div id="showleave">
    <h4 class="mb-4">Pending Requests</h4>
    <?php
        foreach ($leave as $row) {
            echo '
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li class="media border-bottom border-top py-3">
                    <img class="mr-3" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                    <div class="media-body">
                      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">'.$row->user_name.'</h5>
                      <p class="mb-0 mt-0">'.$row->leave_start.' to '.$row->leave_end.'</p>
                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->leave_type.'</p>
                      <p class="mt-0">'.$row->id.'</p>
                      <button type="button" name="addcart" onclick= "leaveArrove(<?php echo $row->id;?>)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pedingLeaveRequest" data-id="'.$row->id.'">View Request</button>
                    </div>
                </li>               
            </ul>
            ';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This didnt work out. The console showed that there is an unexpected token <

Comment: I have not tried by running the code. I just mentioned the way how to resolve the issue. You just pick up button code & write JavaScript code in function, the way I write.